# ifstream best way to read without memory usage

Tags: c++, file, input, ifstream

I have a textfile that contains authors and the books written by authors. I am assigned to write a program in that the user will provide the name of a author. And the program must print the name of any books written by that author.

I understand that i am supposed to use an ifstream to read this information. But how can i make it so my program **doesn't** read the entire file into memory (array, vector, etc.) to perform any of the search queries?

What would be the best way to approach this? my program should use classes as well.

Comment: Please add a homework tag. Read the file and build an index with file offsets - you are effectively creating a database

Comment: No worries ;-) we all forget things, the homework tag will help get you people that are prepared to help with your homework

Comment: Are you saying you can't read the file once and add its contents to a vector?

Comment: I dont want to add the whole contents to the vector, im trying to save memory and have it work as fast as possible.

Comment: Just curious on how to approach a method for this.

Comment: I think you're making this unnecessarily hard on yourself unless this is a requirement.

Comment: Yes its a requirement but im not sure how to approach it

Comment: Like I said build an index - scan the file on startup - store each author/file offset in a std::map. Then you can lookup the author in the map, get the file offset, seek the file to that point and read the rest of the info you need

Comment: I will look into the std::map thing it doesnt hog memory i assume?

Comment: Why can you store into std::map but not std::vector?

Comment: So i think ill follow brian, just scan the entire file, and shove what i need into the vector then output it? This shouldnt use much memory right?

Comment: If you want fast, then you should should save it into vector. If you want a low memory usage then you need to index the file.

Comment: I am confused as what it means to index a file @Caesar

Comment: @soniccool At the start of the program, you could create a dictionary of a string and int. You can than use that to store the name of the author in the string part and in the int you store the offset of where it was found. Than when the user enters the author you look up the dictionary for that author then use the offset to find the books in the text file.
If you want to read about offset you can check this link http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/seekg/
But this is not the fastest approach. The fastest method is to store the whole file in a vector. But that will cost memory

Comment: @soniccool Think of an index as a key/value pair - the key is your search term - the value is where to actually find the data

Comment: @soniccool last thing you should worry about is memory unless you are writing this for embedded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the whole answer, or even the syntax, but a good way to get started is what do you know about the format of the input text file? Is it simply a two-column file like: [Author Book] separated by a common delimiter? In that case, you could construct a loop that goes through the whole file and only store the entries into a vector that match the search string.

Comment: Yeah i was thinking that but i was also thinking about speed, there is 400k lines to this, and its seperated by lines.

Comment: For example one line is the author lines under are the books

Comment: Surely there's a way for you to distinguish between lines with author and lines with titles?

Comment: @soniccool : Are you implying that speed is your primary concern? If so, there are definitely solutions that are faster than the obvious ones, but it sounds to me more like you just need to get it _working_...

Comment: Speed and memory both, but mainly memory. @ildjarn

Comment: Fair enough, but you simply cannot get a concrete answer until you answer @jrok's question -- how do you know whether a line is a book or an author?

Answer (score 1):

A lot here depends on how often you're going to look for books from the file. If yo're only going to look for one or two, then the most sensible method is probably to just scan through the file reading pairs of lines to find the ones you want.

Most other methods assume that you're going to look for data in the file often enough to justify spending some extra time up front to optimize the queries later. Assuming that's correct, one possibility would be to create an index by reading through the file, hashing each author's name, and the position in the file of the "record" for that author/book pair.

Then you'll store those pairs of hash/file offset into a separate file. When you want to do a query, you'll read the hashes/files offsets into memory. Hash the name of the author you're searching for (using the same algorithm) and see which (if any) file offsets have the same hash value. Seek to those spots in the file, and read in the record for the book. At that point, re-compare the author name in the file to the author name that was entered, in case of a hash collision. Show the records where you get a match.