# vector read specific lines

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have a text file that contains names of shows and people who starred in them.

I need to create a vector in a class where i can type in the actor and it will output the movie.

But i don't want to read this whole entry into a vector to save memory.

How can i make it so that i would read this txt file that includes this below, and then finds the actors name for example `Min, Jun So` it will find both instances, then read both movies into the vector and output it?

Just maybe a layout of a code that would do this would be awesome. Just to get me started.

```
Min, Elia
    Starlight Inn (2010)  [Skyler]  <4>

Min, Jun So
    "Joseon X-Files - Secret Book" (2010) {Ghosts of Yidu (#1.6)}  [Choi Eui Shin]  <5>

Min, Jung So
    "Mischievous Kiss" (2010)  [Oh Ha Ni]

Min, Xiao
    Little Sister (2010)  [Mei Mei]  <2>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to read the whole file before picking out the desired lines? You could iterate through the file, finding those lines on the fly. You might also explain how this question relates to [your last one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327239/ifstream-best-way-to-read-without-memory-usage).

Comment: Im just not sure how to code this. Thats my problem.

Comment: How big is that file? Scanning a file is a *lot* slower than just putting all the names in a `std::map` and searching with that.

Comment: I cant load the whole file into memory. Thats the issue. The file is 15mb

Comment: Do you know how to read the whole file and print it out line by line, without holding more than a couple of lines in memory at a time?

Comment: 15MB is not a whole lot these days...and anyway, I didn't advocate reading the whole file into memory, just the author names. You take those, put them in a `std::map` keyed on the name and with file offsets as values.

Comment: Im not aware of how to do this or use that. Where can i researc more about `std::map` and my goal is to use the least amount of memory

Comment: If you're hell-bent on using a constant amount of storage, then you either (a) use linear search (really slow, even for a small file), or (b) load the file and create an on-disk index for faster lookup. If the file is in sorted order, you might be able to pull off a binary search, but it will be cumbersome to code exactly right with an ordinary text file.

Comment: What exactly is the vector for?  Why do you need to use one?

Comment: To store information so i dont load everything in only what i need.

Comment: @nneonneo Please note that [the homework tag is now being phased out and must no longer be used](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100).

Comment: Thanks. I'm quite aware of the change, though this question does predate the tag's obsolescence :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ths sample code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file( "test.txt" ) ;
    std::string search_str = "Elia" ;
    std::string line ;
    int line_number = 0 ;
    std::vector<string> finds;
    finds.resize(100);

    while( std::getline( file, line ) )
    {
        ++line_number ;
        if( line.find(search_str) != std::string::npos )
        {
            std::cout << "line " << line_number << ": " << line << '\n' ;
            finds.push_back(line);
            std::getline( file, line );
            finds.push_back(line);
        }
    }

    for (int i=0;i<finds.size();i++)
    {
        std::cout<<finds[i]<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Input: `Elia`

Output:

```
Min, Elia
    Starlight Inn (2010)  [Skyler]  <4>
Press any key to continue
```

Comment: Why `finds.resize(100)`? Perhaps you meant `finds.reserve(100)`?

Comment: resize()  allocates memory and creates as many instances as the desired   But reserve() only allocates memory, it doesn't create instances.

Comment: You tipically use `resize` when you want to index the vector and `reserve` if you'll use `push_back` (the latter creates instances inside the vector by itself). Right now you've got 100 useless empty strings at the front, you just don't see them when printing out the vector.